# my android app has been suspended and removed from Google Play because it violates our Device and Network Abuse policy and section 4.9 of the

Tags: android

actually, my android app which its function is to show whatsapp groups and enable joining them by clicking a button has been suspended and removed from Google Play because it violates our Device and Network Abuse policy and section 4.9 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.

google play send me this notification :
note that we do not allow apps that access or use a service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service.

actually, I did not try to submit an appeal till I know what is exactly the problem 
but I guess it is because of my app engaging with whatsapp app ,so how to fix this situation

actually, when I am reviewing google play store I realized that my app is not the only one which is suspended many apps that have the same function of my app have been suspended even one of them has more than one million installs where mine has more than 100K installs

public void groupsubscribtion(String groupurl) {

```
    try {



        Intent browserIntent = new Intent();
        browserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(groupurl));
        browserIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        startActivity(browserIntent);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: You should contact Google directly, as we can only guess as to what your app is doing which resulted in it being banned.  I have heard many stories lately of 3rd party apps getting shut out of WhatsApp, so this would not be the first time something like this has happened.

Comment: have you find any solution for this? i have same problem. Please give me answer if you found some alternate way.